# iPhone - Same provisioning profile for different app?

Tags: iphone, provisioning

Can you use the same provisioning profile for compiling 2 different apps for the App Store? I suppose not, but just wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite certain you cannot use wildcards in an appID for App Store Submissions.  You can build and debug all your apps with something like `GK46RTKQ4V.*`, though for an actually app submission you WILL need unique appIDs.

Comment: Why everybody's profile is `GK46RTKQ4V.*`; is `GK46RTKQ4V` some kind of un-Google-able magic string?

Comment: It's not, I just copied and pasted the guys above me.  Too lazy to type in a new one.

Comment: And its not my real ID, I just made up the letters/numbers in that one. But real ones look similar.

Comment: You can use wildcards in an appID in the App Store. I have 3 apps in the store from when it initially launched and they all share the same appID and are still updateable. You just can't do in-app purchase or push notification to apps that share an appID
Sharing an appID also allows multiple apps from the same developer share access to the keychain so info 1 of my apps stores in a user's keychain can be accessed by another app of myne if its sharing the appID.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a profile for any/all apps you want by using a .* at the end of your appID

example:`GK46RTKQ4V.*`

There are draw backs, such as if you want to be able to do in app purchase you need a unique appID.