# different app with same provisioning profile

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have two apps with explicit bundle id and both app has push notification capability. Can I use a same provisioning profile for both the app ids. If yes will I be able to deliver separate push notifications to both the app? . I googled and also searched SO but couldn't find an answer specifically related to delivering push notification separately.

Comment: Provisioning profile corresponds to bundle identifier right ? So how come you have two bundle identifier and one provisioning profile ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I am confused based on the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2692437/334091 hence this post

Comment: You can have one provisioning profile (Bundle id with wild card id) for multiple app Since it is wild card provision, you can't enable push notification for such apps.

Answer (score 1):

For each app you have to create a separate APNS certificate based on the App bundle-Id. Then you have to configure the APNS certificate in your Push notification server/ Push notification service you are using. Refer this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW11

> You use Member Center to generate a push notification client SSL certificate that allows your notification server to connect to the APNs. Each App ID is required to have its own client SSL certificate. The client SSL certificate Member Center generates is a universal certificate that allows your app to connect to both the development and production environments.

Answer (score 1):

For each app there should be separate APNS certificates. APNS certificates comprises of App ID and the build ID's. Push notifications will be sent based on the App ID in the certificates.  So separate APNS certificates should be there.

[REFERENCE LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW11)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

---

APN server register your device w.r.t your app (bundle-id) with xcode generated xxx.p12 cirtificate (Development and Production). At a time it work one which one last register with APNs (Device Token).During evelopment you may test push notification but In case production won't work.